Exporting models with Color Ramps doesn't work/Bake textures not working either
So i am doing a university project and I'm trying to make a recipe website that as 3D models in it. For this i need to export the 3D models that i made, but when i export them, they always come without a texture because i have color ramps and things like that creating the textures instead of an image. I already tried to bake the textures, but it doesnt work, because the way that the colors are created is by light shining in the object, and when i bake the textures they just come with one color, does anyone know how i can bake the textures with the light effects. Can someone help me?

Hello and welcome. It seem you need help with baking something, if that is the case, could you edit your post and rephrase it to focus on that? Be clear why the results you achieved are insufficient? Be sure to show the ramps you want to bake, and how they were made, the light setup, the materials involved and how they should look, otherwise it is impossible for us to help. Be sure to look at existing questions about baking to be sure they don't address you issues
